# Flexslider - start on specific slide depending on anchor?

Tags: jquery, slider, flexslider

Is there a way to get [flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) to start at specific slide depending an anchor link?

eg.

http://site.com/index.html#slide1 - start at slide 1

http://site.com/index.html#slide3 - start at slide 3

I would like to set it up as a variable on the **startAt** option that would say something like

if window.location.hash is **number** , start at **number**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flexslider have an option **startAt**, it accepts integer value of your slide index.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a little bit of Coffeescript (or JS if you like that more), but only works on desktop devices so far

```
# Add support for hashtags
$(window).load ->
  # Get your hash tag
  loc = $(location).attr('href')
  idx = 1
  if(loc.lastIndexOf('#') != -1)
    idx = loc.substr(loc.lastIndexOf('#')+1).replace('slide', '')
  # verify that idx is really a number
  if(isNaN(idx-0))
    idx = 1
  # Click on your nav (idx starts at 0)
  $('.flex-control-nav li:eq('+(idx-1)+') a').trigger('click')
```